# How to find the size of data returned from a table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I have a table the holds snapshots of data. These snapshots are all tagged with `'jan2010'` or `'april2011'`. All the snapshots will grow exponentially over time and I wanted to see if I could forecast when we'd need to upgrade our storage.

Is there any way to

```
select monthlysnapshot, sum(size)
from tblclaims_liberty 
group by monthlysnapshot 
order by monthlysnapshot desc
```

What am I missing to get the size of the data returned? Is there a system function I can call?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EXEC sp_spaceused 'tablename'**

This will return a single result set that provides the following information:

Name - the name of the table

Rows - the number of rows in the table

Reserved - amount of total reserved space for the table

Data - amount of space used by the data for the table

Index_Size - amount of space used by the table's indexes

Unused - amount of usused space in the table

Comment: using this i calculated the space used by each snapshot and was able to forcast when i should think about expanding. thanks. :)

Answer (score 1):

Is it what you are looking for?

<strike>[C# Getting the size of the data returned from and SQL query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2365703/c-getting-the-size-of-the-data-returned-from-and-sql-query)</strike>

Changed:

```
EXEC sp_spaceused 'tablename'
```

**If you can do this in your code then in C# (Change code to whatever lang you are using)**

```
long size = 0;
object o = new object();
using (Stream s = new MemoryStream()) {
BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
formatter.Serialize(s, o);
size = s.Length;
```

Code copied from: [How to get object size in memory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605621/how-to-get-object-size-in-memory/3173599#3173599)

Comment: I think the title and the final question are in contradiction to the other information supplied. It's more like the OP wants to know the size of certain data *stored* rather than *returned*.

Comment: that exactly my problem. all my data is in the one table. i want to know how much the data will frow for each snapshot.

Comment: @Adam McC can you do this in your code. If you are using C# then look at my Edit.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can Insert the selected data into a table via "select * into newtable from table" and get the size of that newly created table.