# Determine length of SQL Server 2005 XML Data returned

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

Is there a way to predermine the length of returned XML Data from SQL Server.

Ex:

```
SELECT *
FROM Products
FOR XML RAW, ROOT('products')
```

I am using SQL Server 2005.

Comment: See this post once http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6108272/how-to-find-the-size-of-data-returned-from-a-table

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT DATALENGTH (
                    (SELECT *
                    FROM products
                    FOR XML RAW, ROOT('products')
                    ) 
                )
```

It will give to you size in bytes.
for details, see here:
[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173486(v=SQL.90).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173486%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx)